# Image-Scaling "too late" when not centered (on windows-resize)

Tags: css, image-scaling, window-resize

I'm not finding any information on this. Might be because my approach is incorrect.

I'm having my image positioned absolutely under a div which uses full window width. 
I'm using `margin-left: 30%`, so that images are always positioned 30% from the left border.
Everything else is set for responsive image handling..

I got the code correct that it scales like I want if the browser-window gets resized.
**But because the image is not centered, the scaling happens "too late", so the right part will be hidden outside view**.

Can I solve this with the scaling starting "earlier"?
Or using sth different than margin-left: 30% or left: 30% ?

see here: [JsFiddle - Image out of view when resizing window](http://jsfiddle.net/sYv9r/1/)

```
img.aaa
{
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 85%;
    max-height: 85%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin-left: auto` which will center the image. If it has to be a certain distance from the left, use a container div and the following css. This will prevent the image from going outside the body and getting cut off.

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 30%;
    //text-align: center; //remove padding and uncomment this to center image in div
}
img.aaa {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 85%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sYv9r/4/)**

Comment: Thanks. This works. But that way, I don't get the image centered vertically anymore. A hint?

Comment: This works, but seems to be overkill: [use margin-left in container](http://jsfiddle.net/sYv9r/7/)

Comment: And I found out, this also kinda solves the problem, but as I want to set css shadows, it's not working good enough: [padding-left in img-class](http://jsfiddle.net/sYv9r/8/). The advantage is, it doesn't need a container-div. Also, I need this to be compatible with all browsers ;) - not sure about that.

Comment: You can use `margin-left: 15%` instead of 30% in your original code. Since you're using `max-width: 85%`, 85 + 15 will put you at a total max-width of 100%.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, that won't help me, as I need the left border of the image to be at exact 30% from the left (and the right border so that it is always a little bit inside the window).  ALso, I like your example  but do you have an idea how to get the vertical alignment centered with that?  Currently I use my 2nd-comment option, but it's full of unnecessary css I fear :-/   I like my 3rd example most, but can't find a way to get rid of the issue with the css-shadow in the padding-area.

Comment: hmm still not the optimal solution. Can someone be so kind and look throu the examples given here and if one of them should be used?